# ClassCastException when saving object in Spring redis session

Tags: java, spring-cloud, jedis, spring-session

Using spring boot 1.3.0.RC1, we used @EnableRedisHttpSession to enable RedisHttpSession.

We tried to save an object in session :

```
ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
        HttpSession session = attr.getRequest().getSession();
        TestUser testObject = new TestUser();
        session.setAttribute("test", testObject);
```

TestUser  implements Serializable.

When we try to get this session object from other method, we receive **nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: test.common.session.security.TestUser cannot be cast to test.common.session.security.TestUser**

```
    2016-02-01_09:14:58.449 [ERROR] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: test.common.session.security.TestUser cannot be cast to test.common.session.security.TestUser] with root cause
java.lang.ClassCastException: test.common.session.security.TestUser cannot be cast to test.common.session.security.TestUser
    at test.gateway.web.rest.AccountResource.getAccount(AccountResource.java:143) ~[classes/:na]
    at test.gateway.web.rest.AccountResource$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ebc3dac2.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at test.gateway.aop.logging.LoggingAspect.logAround(LoggingAspect.java:51) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:68) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:58) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.TimedMethodInterceptor.invoke(TimedMethodInterceptor.java:48) ~[metrics-spring-3.1.2.jar:na]
    at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.TimedMethodInterceptor.invoke(TimedMethodInterceptor.java:34) ~[metrics-spring-3.1.2.jar:na]
    at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.AbstractMetricMethodInterceptor.invoke(AbstractMetricMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[metrics-spring-3.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at test.gateway.web.rest.AccountResource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f8717e0c.getAccount(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) ~[spring-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) ~[spring-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:806) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:729) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at com.codahale.metrics.servlet.AbstractInstrumentedFilter.doFilter(AbstractInstrumentedFilter.java:104) ~[metrics-servlet-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:242) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.3.0.RC1.jar:1.3.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:111) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.3.0.RC1.jar:1.3.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:157) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at test.gateway.web.filter.CsrfCookieGeneratorFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfCookieGeneratorFilter.java:37) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:96) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) ~[spring-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) ~[spring-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) ~[spring-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:125) ~[spring-session-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:65) ~[spring-session-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85) ~[spring-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_40]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_40]
```

Comment: Try to add more code

Comment: You mean spring configuration?

Comment: This answer from another question has the underlying reason for this and a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62801955/2881450

Answer (score 1):

I am facing similar Issue. Based on the discussion going on here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4565 it seems DevTools are causing some issue.

I removed `spring-boot-devtools` and it is working fine.